# Sum of powers of prime factors

Tags: algorithm, prime-factoring

Given an array of integers (each <=10^6) what is the fastest way to find the sum of powers of prime factors of  each integer?

```
Ex:- 
    array: 4 6 12 7
    4 -> 2^2 -> 2
    6 -> 2^1 * 3^1 -> 1+1 -> 2
    12 -> 2^2 * 3^1 -> 2+1 -> 3
    7 -> 7^1 -> 1
    Answer: 2+2+3+1 = 8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce the time for finding the prime-factors of a number using `sieve algorithm`. For your question, some modification in the sieve algorithm will work.

You can do this,

```
// For Globally storing the sum of power of prime factors
public static int powerSum[] = new int[1000001];

// For Identifying the factor is prime or not
public static boolean prime[] = new boolean[1000001];  

public static void sieve()
{
    powerSum[0] = 0;
    powerSum[1] = 1;

    Arrays.fill(prime , true);

    prime[0] = false;
    prime[1] = false;

    for(int i = 2 ; i <= 1000000 ; i++)     // sieve algorithm
    {
        if(prime[i])   // Consider the factor for calculation only if it is prime
        {
            for(int j = i ; j <= 1000000 ; j += i)
            {
                int tempJ = j;

                while(tempJ != 0 && tempJ%i == 0)// Counting number of occurance of the factor
                {
                    powerSum[j]++;

                    tempJ /= i;
                }

                prime[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the sieve method, I'm pre calculating the sum of powers of prime factors of every number between given range. I use the simple sieve method for considering  only prime factors, and for counting the occurrence of that factor, I apply while loop.

Now you can use this method for finding the sum of power of prime factors for any number in given range by this way,

```
public static void main(String args[])
{   
    sieve();

    int ans = powerSum[4] + powerSum[6] + powerSum[7] + powerSum[12];

    System.out.println(ans);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-prime-factors-of-a-given-number/) out and try to adapt something from there. Happy mathing!

```
// Print the number of 2s that divide n
    while (n%2 == 0)
    {
        printf("%d ", 2);
        n = n/2;
    }

    // n must be odd at this point.  So we can skip 
    // one element (Note i = i +2)
    for (int i = 3; i <= sqrt(n); i = i+2)
    {
        // While i divides n, print i and divide n
        while (n%i == 0)
        {
            printf("%d ", i);
            n = n/i;
        }
    }

    // This condition is to handle the case when n 
    // is a prime number greater than 2
    if (n > 2)
        printf ("%d ", n);
```

You could possibly use the above algorithm on the product of all the integers in your array and obtain the same result, potentially faster due to saving time on all the add operations on the individual level.

Comment: The link in your post is broken

Comment: This will take much time if we do this for every element in the array to find the sum.

Comment: The speed must come from how fast finding the prime factors on each individual integer are computed. I believe this is the fastest way. It is inherently going to be slow due to the nature of computing potentially 10^6 integers in the operation individually.

Comment: What if you multiplied all numbers in the array by each other and then compute the above algorithm on the result? The multiplication should retain the factors and their powers on an addition basis.